# Elasticsearch: Search for a group of summed fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a benchmark index with data from for hospital wards and I want to know the medication usages for a wards location per week.

The problem now is that when I select a week of data, the population for a location with multiple wards will be calculated wrong. I want to know the average population for a location in that week. The location's population is the sum of the population from the wards within the location

```
{
    "_index": "development_benchmark",
    "_type": "score",
    "_id": "3147603",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "id": 3147603,
      "score": 86,
      "amount": 1758.7,
      "population": 2045,
      "date": "2018-01-12T03:00:00+01:00",
      "benchmark_id": 10,
      "ward": {
        "id": 24170,
        "ward_types": [
          3
        ]
      },
      "location_id": 24285,
      "cluster_id": 72997
    }
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
GET development_benchmark/_search
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
        {
            "range": {
            "date": {
                "gte": "2017-12-20",
              "lte": "2017-12-20"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "benchmarks": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "benchmark_id",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
            "clusterScore": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                    "cluster_id": 72997
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
              "amount": {
                  "sum": {
                      "field": "amount"
                  }
              },
              "population": {
                  "sum": {
                      "field": "population"
                  }
              },
              "locations": {
                  "terms": {
                            "field": "location_id",
                "size": 1000
              },
              "aggs": {
                            "amount": {
                                "sum": {
                                    "field": "amount"
                  }
                },
                "population": {
                                "sum": {
                                    "field": "population"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to aggregate the locations like:

```
"locations"  => [
        "terms" => [
            "field" => "location_id",
            "size"  => 1000
        ],

        "aggs" => [
            "wards"      => [
                "terms" => [
                    "field" => "ward.id",
                    "size"  => 1000
                ],
                "aggs"  => [
                    "amount"     => [
                        "avg" => [
                            "field" => "amount"
                        ]
                    ],
                    "population" => [
                        "avg" => [
                            "field" => "population"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "amount"     => [
                "sum_bucket" => [
                    "buckets_path" => "wards>amount"
                ]
            ],
            "population" => [
                "sum_bucket" => [
                    "buckets_path" => "wards>population"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

This calculates the average population for a ward in the selected time. Then sums all the average ward populations for every location